# react-select map options population

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am having problems mapping an array of items to populate a dropdown in react-select.  I have it working in reactstrap, but cant figure out how to convert it.

Here is the working reactstrap version:

```
                            <ButtonDropdown isOpen={this.state.metricCategoryDropdownOpen} size="xs" color="secondary" toggle={this.metricCategoryToggle}>
                                <DropdownToggle caret>
                                {this.state.metricCategoryDropdownValue}
                                </DropdownToggle>
                                <DropdownMenu>
                                {metricCategoryNames.map((title, categoryIndex) => 
                                    (<DropdownItem
                                    key={categoryIndex}
                                    active={categoryIndex === this.state.metricCategoryActive}
                                    style={{height: 28}}
                                    >
                                    <div onClick={this.metricCategoryHandleClick}>{title}</div>
                                    </DropdownItem>))
                                }
                                </DropdownMenu>
                            </ButtonDropdown>
```

I have tried all sorts of ways to get it to populate, but here is the last failed attempt which is just based on their simple sample:

```
                            <Select
                                name="form-field-name"
                                value={value}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}

                                options = {metricCategoryNames.map((key, text) =>
                                (
                                    value= {key},
                                    label= {text}
                                ))}

                            />
```

Thanks for the help, this works for me:

```
                            <Select
                                name="form-field-name"
                                value={value}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                options={
                                    metricCategoryNames.map((e, key) => ({
                                        label: e,
                                        value: key,
                                 }))
                             }
                            />
```

Comment: With a quick check of the documentation I noticed you need to pass an array of objects to your options. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Try this for your options

```
options = {metricCategoryNames.map((key, text) => {
    return {
        value: key,
        label: text
    };}
)}
```